Undergraduates Mathematics Research Paper and Future Path
I am a third-year mathematics student at University in Malaysia, which is ranked between 350-400 in the QS World University Rankings. I plan to continue master study, but when I checked the requirement for master's programs, I found that some schools require research experience. In my understanding, this means that I need to publish a research paper. I was very confused. My CGPA is currently 3.15/4.0. I was not a genius, but I work very hard in my studies. However, when I see the research experience requirement, I feel like very nervous. I don't know how to start a research project or how to publish a research paper. I have asked my professors, and they told me that published a research paper when undergraduates study is not an easy job.
My questions are:

If my undergraduate university's QS ranking is not so high, does it mean I won't be able to get into a good university for a math master's degree?

How can I start to write a research paper?

I am currently working on my thesis, which is on fuzzy topological spaces. I really enjoy this topic. I asked my supervisor if I could use my thesis to publish a research paper, but he said my work is too easy and have a low chance to be published. Can anyone give me some advice?


Thanks everyone.

No, you do not need to publish a paper.

Could you specify whether you would like to get your Master degree also at a university in Malaysia or in another country?

@JochenGlueck Thanks for answering. I am planning to apply NUS (National University of Singapore). Since my university is near China and Australia, I also plan to apply university in both countries. Currently I didn't consider continue study at Malaysia. If in US or Europe, the tuition fee and living cost will be bit high for me so unless I can get a scholarship then I will go there.

I'm a PhD student in the UK so there may be cultural differences here. If you haven't already asked your supervisor about the research experience requirement and how people normally meet it then that should be your first step.
Research experience doesn't necessarily mean publishing a paper, and you certainly wouldn't be expected to be publishing independently at this stage. Ask your supervisor or another professor whose work you are interested in if they have a project you might be able to assist with to gain some research experience. For example, I am in Computer Science and we have undergraduates help with small pieces of programming in ongoing research projects. They will be more likely to accept if you can make it seem like an offer that will help them rather than additional work for them, and they will also be more likely to accept if they already know you to be reliable and easy to communicate with.
I suggest sending a polite email saying you're looking to gain some research experience, your particular strengths are x and y, you can commit up to z hours a week for the next however many weeks, and do they have any projects you may be able to assist with. I would only email one person and wait until they accept or reject, as if you email multiple people, two accept, and then you back out, this will be annoying to them. Give whoever you email a week or two to respond, and send at most one follow up email if you get no response. If you don't get a response after a couple of weeks I would consider that to be a rejection.

Thank you for your answer, it helps me a lot.
